# How to make provide/inject reactive in Vue 3 to avoid props drilling?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a root component that has a lot of descendants. In order to avoid props drilling, I want to use provide/inject.

In the root component in the setup function, I use `provide`.
In the child component in the setup function, I get the value via `inject`.

Then the child component might emit an event, that forces the root component to reload data that it provides to the child components.

However, the data in the child component is not changed.

Previous answers that I found usually were related to Vue 2, and I'm struggling with Vue 3 composition API.

I tried to use watch/watchEffect, and "re-provide" the data, but it didn't work (and I'm not sure if it's a good solution).

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-diffie-e3eqyq

Comment: Did you gave a read to this one? https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Comment: @Victor Please show the relevant code in the question so that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-diffie-e3eqyq . I provided some comments inside the App/Child components

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to be that guy, but read the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity)!
Anyway:

App.vue

```
 setup() {
    let randomNumber = ref(Math.random());

    function updateRandomNumber() {
      randomNumber.value = Math.random()
    }
    // This should be an AJAX call to re-configurate all the children
    // components. All of them needs some kind of config.
    // How to "re-provide" the data after a child component asked this?


    provide("randomNumber", {
      randomNumber,
      updateRandomNumber
    });
  },
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>Child component</div>
  <button @click="updateRandomNumber">Ask root component for re-init</button>
  <div>Injected data: {{ randomNumber }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    // How to "re-inject" the data from parent?
    const {randomNumber, updateRandomNumber} = inject("randomNumber");

    return {
      randomNumber,
      updateRandomNumber
    };
  },
};
</script>
```